# Selenium IDE element xpath finder code

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-ide

I am working on javascript in which I need to get the proper xpath of the element (Like we get in selenium IDE plugin in Firefox).

Is there any way I can get the function which selenium IDE is using to find xpath, so that I can integrate it in my javascript code.

**I really need this.**

Comment: Sounds like XY problem. What is it that you are actually trying to solve?

Comment: how about learning to build xpath on your own?

Comment: @wilx  I have javascript program which should return me xpath of element that I click on webpage...

Comment: @KirilS. Why to spend time on a thing which is already made by someone... ;)

Comment: Because tools don't create optimal or logical xpaths. For example if I specify element xpath as `//*[@id="question"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div/div[2]/a[2]` (which was suggested by automated tool), I created 3 problems: 1-can you tell what is this element? (it's on this SO page); 2-if page changes even slightly, such path will break, and then good luck searching for what it was; 3-searching for `//*` is worst in terms of performance.

Comment: Manually I would create the following xpath for the same element (one way, there are others as well): `//a[@rel='tag' and text()='selenium']`. Which is easy to understand (it practically spells what it is), easy to change if it breaks (but probability of it breaking is much lower than the first one), and is efficient at search.

Answer (score 1):

You could try with [FirePath](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firepath/), it can easily create xpath or css selectors you need. You have to install [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/?src=dp-dl-dependencies) first.

Comment: I dont want any application to find xpath. I need the code, maybe a function which I can use in my javascript

Answer (score 0):

If you check out the Github for Selenium IDE, it uses WGX(Wicked Good Xpath).  Here's the link to the code. https://github.com/google/wicked-good-xpath

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/ceaf3da79542024becdda5953059dfbb96fb3a90/third_party/js/wgxpath/wgxpath.js

- Klendathu